# Datomic: 'Not in collection' query is not working

Tags: database, clojure, datomic

I’m trying to fetch all users from database, except those related to a set of UID’s.
I have written this query but when UIDs list has more than one element, for some reason, the “not” clause does not work and it returns me all registered users.

```
(d/q '[:find (pull ?e [*])
   :in $ [?uids ...]
    :where [?e :user/id ?uid]
           (not [?e :user/id ?uids])]
 db ["user-uid-1" "user-uid-2" "user-uid-3"])
```

When UID’s list contains a single element, the query works properly (it returns all users, except the user with specified UID).

Any ideas of what could be wrong?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem here :/

Comment: I don't have a running instance at my disposal at the moment so I am sorry that I can't help you directly but one option is to call Clojure functions https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/query/query.html#calling-clojure. That doc page is also handy for other operations that you can do.

Comment: Currently, as a palliative measure, i am calling the Clojure functions. I don't want to use the Clojure functions because of the performance issues. Thank you very much, @ClariceBouwer

Answer (score 1):

Using `[?uids ...]` acts like `SELECT * FROM user WHERE id != uid1 UNION SELECT * FROM user WHERE id != uid2` instead of the expected `SELECT * FROM user WHERE id NOT IN (uids)`

For example in the below sample query trying to get all fruits that are not an apple or pear

```clj
(d/q
  '[:find ?id ?fruit ?fruits
    :in $ [?fruits ...]
    :where
    [?id :fruit ?fruit]
    (not [?id :fruit ?fruits])]
  [[1 :fruit :apple]
   [2 :fruit :orange]
   [3 :fruit :pear]]
  [:apple :pear])
; => #{[3 :pear :apple] [2 :orange :pear] [1 :apple :pear] [2 :orange :apple]}
```

we see that the query runs for every fruit in our list. `:pear` gives `[2 :orange :pear] [1 :apple :pear]` and `:apple` gives `[3 :pear :apple] [2 :orange :apple]`.

In order to find all the items not in a collection you'll want to make the collection a set and send it over in a scalar binding like so

```clj
(d/q
  '[:find ?id ?fruit ?fruits
    :in $ ?fruits
    :where
    [?id :fruit ?fruit]
    (not [(?fruits ?fruit)])]
  [[1 :fruit :apple]
   [2 :fruit :orange]
   [3 :fruit :pear]]
  #{:apple :pear})
; => #{[2 :orange #{:apple :pear}]}
```

in your case you'll want to rewrite the query like so

```clj
(d/q '[:find (pull ?e [*])
   :in $ ?uids
    :where [?e :user/id ?uid]
           (not [(?uids ?uid)]
 db #{"user-uid-1" "user-uid-2" "user-uid-3"})
```